Junit 5 "ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [java.lang.String arg0]"
I want to test this constructor with different name parameters.
public Horse(String name, double speed, double distance) {
    if (isNull(name)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null.");
    } else if (name.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be blank.");
    }
    if (speed < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Speed cannot be negative.");
    }
    if (distance < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Distance cannot be negative.");
    }

    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.distance = distance;
}

public Horse(String name, double speed) {
    this(name, speed, 0);
}

The test looks like
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {" ", "\t", "     "})
void Constructor_Empty_String_Message(String s){
    //given
    //when
    //then
    try{
        new Horse(s,0);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Assertions.assertEquals("Name cannot be blank.",e.toString());
    }
}

Full exeption statrace:
Full exeption statrack
I think it's a problem with ParameterResolver but I don't know how to fix it.
I'm using Junit 5.8.0 and junit-jupiter-params 5.11.0-M2.

Please do not show text as an image. Instead, include the text in the body of the question as text. Use copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

You're getting a ClassNotFoundException because your versions don't match. The version of junit-jupiter-api, junit-jupiter-engine, and junit-jupiter-params should all be the same.

The source of the error is indeed the fact you're mixing dependency versions. JUnit Jupiter provides a single jar dependency, and for most usecases, including this one, using it would be the easiest path forward. Personally. I'd go with the latest stable version at the time of writing, 5.10.3:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.10.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

But if you're intent on using 5.11.0-M1, you could do that too:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.0-M1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Having said that, the test itself is wrong - you're comparing the exception's message to the result of its toString(), which also includes the class name. Instead, you should use getMessage():
Assertions.assertEquals("Name cannot be blank.", e.getMessage());

Moreover, there are two mistakes in the implementation of the assertion in the catch block.
First, it catches an Exception, and not the specific IllegalArgumentException. If the Horse constructor were to throw a different exception with that message, the test would (wrongly) pass.
Second, if the constructor does not throw any exception, the catch block will never be reached, and the test will silently pass.
Using assertThrows makes it easy to solve both those issues:
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {" ", "\t", "     "})
void Constructor_Empty_String_Message(String s) {
    IllegalArgumentException e = 
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, 
                                () -> new Horse(s, 0));
    Assertions.assertEquals("Name cannot be blank.",e.getMessage());
}

